# How to expose camel producer with jmx

Tags: apache-camel, jmx

I read the documentation about camel jmx. In my case i want to expose some attributes and operations of a Producer (made a custom component).
There seems to be no example for jmx on producers and all screenshots showing jConsole i saw doesn't show a "folder" producers (while consumers and endpoints are present).
But i tried to annotate my producer class with @ManagedResource, @ManagedAttribute and @ManagedOperation but it doesn't work (or where to look in jconsole?)

Some ducumentations mention an interface to be implemented "ManagementAware" but this is deprecated.

So how to expose producers with jmx?

Comment: I believe, depending on how the objectname is configured, the bean may appear under a corresponding node in the jconsole->Mbeans-> ... tree; in some cases it can default to a generic package/objectname which puts it under MBeans->bean->beanName for example. Did you expand *all* the nodes in jconsole, and it wasn't under *any* of them?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check out this http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html#CamelJMX-RegisteringyourownManagedEndpoints?

Comment: @Willem i checked this out. "ManagementAware" is deprecated. I used the annotations. On consumer all works fine - i find the mbeat in category "consumers". But how to annotate/name a producer and how to find it in jconsole?